# Why am I getting an error while running Selenium Grid through eclipse?

Tags: selenium, junit, grid

I am new to selenium, as given in selenium site I started selenium hub by using:

```
ant launch-hub
```

I launched remote control by using:

```
ant launch-remote-control
```

and then started running testcase from eclipse. The server launched a
   browser then it did not perform anything.

It gave an error like (garbage unavailable rc's and slate)and some forums says that I have
   to create xml files..

So, I want to know what is the process to run in a different browser. I am using `junit` I this might change the process.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you have an old version of Selenium RC that does not support your version of Firefox (or whatever you use). Download the latest version of [Selenium RC](http://seleniumhq.org/download/) and follow the [instructions](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2):

Step 1: Start the hub

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar -role hub
```

Step 2: Start the nodes

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register
```

Using grid to run tests

```
Selenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://www.google.com");
```